# How to log multple users on in Squid access log.

Tags: ssh, squid, linux-networking

I have a Squid proxy where a few users come in thrum SSH. They they are forwarding ports through the tunnel. This has the side affect of thinking all users host is 127.0.0.1 in squid access log. So I can not tell the users apart when parsing the logs. Any thoughts? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Make 'em authenticate to the proxy, or disable SSH port forwarding.  If you really need to know who's using the proxy (or at least who's responsible for the use) then authentication is the way to go; if you just want to make the leeches think again, perhaps go the latter.  I'd wonder why you'd let random users SSH into your production proxy server, though...

Comment: Yeah already looked at that. It is not something I want to do. Since the proxy is only listing on local host and the key based authentication to the SSH server is enough. These are not random users. Just a couple friends. I just thought it would be interesting to parse out bandwidth usage. Thanks though!!